# There is no extension able to load the configuration for "facebookbundle" symfony2

Tags: symfony

I create my own FacebookBundle and

I got this error:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for
>   "facebookbundle" (in /facebookx/app/config/config_dev.yml). Looked for
>   namespace "facebookbundle", found "framework", "security", "twig",
>   "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine",
>   "sensio_framework_extra", "jms_aop", "jms_di_extra",
>   "jms_security_extra", "d_facebook", "d_user", "d_security",
>   "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"

The error message means that I got an entry "facebookbundle" in My config.yml which is not used by any extension ?

My config.yml

```
facebookbundle:
    file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../src/FacebookBundle/Facebook/FacebookInit.php
    alias:  facebook
    app_id: xxx
    secret: xxx
    cookie: true
    permissions: [email, user_birthday, user_location, user_about_me]
```

My DFacebookExtension

```
<?php

namespace D\FacebookBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class DFacebookExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');

        foreach (array('app_id', 'secret', 'cookie', 'permissions') as $attribute) {
            $container->setParameter('facebookbundle.'.$attribute, $config[$attribute]);
        }

        if (isset($config['file']) && $container->hasDefinition('acebookbundle.api')) {
            $facebookApi = $container->getDefinition('facebookbundle.api');
            $facebookApi->setFile($config['file']);
        }
    }
}
```

were is error ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In order for custom config parameters to be accepted you have to define your bundle configuration using a Configuration.php class within your bundle.

**src/FacebookBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php:**

```php
<?php
namespace FacebookBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

/**
 * This is the class that validates and merges configuration from your app/config files
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#cookbook-bundles-extension-config-class}
 */
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('facebookbundle');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('file')->defaultValue('')->end()
                ->scalarNode('alias')->defaultValue('')->end()
                ->scalarNode('app_id')->defaultValue('')->end()
                ->scalarNode('secret')->defaultValue('')->end()
                ->booleanNode('cookie')->defaultTrue()->end()
                ->arrayNode('permissions')
                    ->canBeUnset()->prototype('scalar')->end()->end()
            ->end()
            ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: okej, thanks. Do you now how can I get this data(etc. app_id, secret) in my class?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a basic config definition based on your original YML config format. I haven't tested it so it might need a little tweaking.

Comment: My question might shed some light on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482622/creating-a-configuration-file-in-symfony2/32502618#32502618

Comment: I am stuck with the error https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection/blob/master/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php#L657 but I have a full extension file compliant with bundle names, my root config follows the bundle name so my Dependency injection Configuration.php loads root my_company_app based on the bundle name MyCompanyAppBundle. I am loading the bundle in registerBundles in the app kernel. The configuration is obviously loading because i get the error. I have no clue on what I am missing. Any idea?

Comment: Here is a Gist with all the files. if anyone has any idea on what I am missing pls let me know https://gist.github.com/bizmate/82b4694d53ac23eac315a032bf41e6a5

Answer (score 76):

Also, keep in mind that **the root key of the configuration file must be a normalized form of the Bundle's name**.

This is something I've encoutered a few times and it's very frustrating to solve if you're not aware of it.

Example: if bundle is called `MyFirstAwesomeBundle`, then the root key in the file must be `my_first_awesome`. So camel-case is converted to snake-case and the word "bundle" is ignored or stripped away.

So simply having the root key in your file match exactly the value specified in `Configuration::getConfigTreeBuilder()` is not enough.

If you don't follow this rule, then you'll get the `There is no extension able to load the configuration` error.

---

I hope this will help the next desperate soul who ends up on this page...

Comment: Is `YourBundleExtension` exist in your bundle dependency directory? In some case this reason make **There is no extension able to load the configuration** error happen.

Comment: "If you don't follow this rule, then you'll get the There is no extension able to load the configuration error." <- THIS, THANK YOU! You've just solved an intermittent issue I've had for a few years now. I had no idea names were this relevant.

Comment: What is the point in specifying the required param in `$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('my_desired_root_key')` then? Seems like it's completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 13):

This happens when you forget to start the bundle in app/AppKernel.php :

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{

   public function registerBundles()
   {
      $bundles = array (
              new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
              new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
              new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
              new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
              new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
              new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
              new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
              new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
              new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
              //...
              new D\FacebookBundle\DFacebookBundle(),
              //...
      );

      if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array ('dev', 'test')))
      {
         $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
         $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
         $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
      }

      return $bundles;
   }

   public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
   {
      $loader->load(__DIR__ . '/config/config_' . $this->getEnvironment() . '.yml');
   }

}
```

Comment: new FOS\FacebookBundle\FOSFacebookBundle() ? I write my own FacebookBundle

Comment: oups, your own bundle of course ! I see a potential mistake in your src/FacebookBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php, the namespace misses the prefix D\

Answer (score 6):

This error can also be caused by a missing or invalid `services` key at the root of your config. It should look something like this:

```
services:
    foo_bar.baz:
        class: Foo\BarBundle\Service\BazService
```

Comment: Thanks -  in my case the 'services' key was there but indentation was wrong.