# There is no extension able to load the

Tags: api, symfony

I integrating of bundles FOSRestBundle,JMSSerializerBundle and NelmioApiDocBundle, I modified the files config.yml and routing.yml but I find this problem

code config.yml:

```
imports:
            - { resource: parameters.yml }
            - { resource: security.yml }
            - { resource: services.yml }
            - { resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

        # Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
        parameters:
            locale: fr

        framework:
            #esi:             ~
            translator:      ~ 
            secret:          "%secret%"
            router:
                resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
                strict_requirements: ~
            form:            ~
            csrf_protection: ~
            validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
            #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
            templating:
                engines: ['twig']
            default_locale:  "%locale%"
            trusted_hosts:   ~
            trusted_proxies: ~
            session:
                # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
                handler_id:  ~
            fragments:       ~
            http_method_override: true

        # Twig Configuration
        twig:
            debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
            strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

        # Doctrine Configuration
        doctrine:
            dbal:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
                #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
                #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
                #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
                #   3. Uncomment next line:
                #     path:     "%database_path%"

            orm:
                auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true

        # Swiftmailer Configuration
        swiftmailer:
            transport: "%mailer_transport%"
            host:      "%mailer_host%"
            username:  "%mailer_user%"
            password:  "%mailer_password%"
            spool:     { type: memory }

        fos_user:
            db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
            firewall_name: main
            user_class: test\UserBundle\Entity\User

        fos_rest:
            view:
                view_response_listener: 'force'
                formats:
                    json: true
            format_listener:
                rules:
                    - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true }
                    - { path: '^/', stop: true }

        nelmio_cors:
            paths:
                '^/api/':
                    allow_credentials: true
                    allow_origin: ['*']
                    allow_headers: ['*']
                    allow_methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
                    max_age: 3600
```

code routing.yml:

```
user:
        resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        prefix:   /

    med:
        resource: "@MedBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        prefix:   /

    app:
        resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
        type:     annotation

    fos_user:
        resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

    NelmioApiDocBundle:
        resource: "@NelmioApiDocBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        prefix:   /api/doc

    app_api:
        resource: "@MedBundle/Resources/config/routing_rest.yml"
        type:     rest
        prefix:   /api
```

code routing_rest.yml:

```
api_app:
resource: MedBundle\Controller\Api\AppController
type:     rest
```

code AppController.php:

```
<?php

    namespace test\MedBundle\Controller\Api;

    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RouteResource;



    /**
     * @RouteResource("User")
     */
    Class AppController extends Controller  {

        public function getAction() {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $test = $em->getRepository('MedBundle:Apps')->findAll();
            return array("test" => $test);
        }


        public function postAction(Request $request){

            return $request->request->all();

        }

    }
```

Now I find this problem when it can test API

[image]

What is the solution and thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no extension able to load the configuration for "facebookbundle" symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741632/there-is-no-extension-able-to-load-the-configuration-for-facebookbundle-symfon)

Comment: try check [this doc about howto use assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html). check if the composer is aligned and the bundle is loaded in the appkernel files

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any configuration for assetic in your config.yml file. I assume you don't have the AsseticBundle installed on your app. Since Symfony 2.8, Assetic is no longer included by default in the Symfony Standard Edition. You need to install it yourself:

First require the bundle with composer:

```
composer require symfony/assetic-bundle
```

Enable the bundle in the AppKernel.php file

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    // ...

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            // ...
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        );

        // ...
    }
}
```

add the following minimal configuration to your config.yml file to enable Assetic

```
# app/config/config.yml
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```