# Symfony:There is no extension able to load the configuration for "service"

Tags: php, symfony

Am trying to make Google login in my site, using this 
 [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle)

In my site am getting this error:

`ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 17:`

`Attempted to load class "FOSUserBundle" from namespace "FOS\UserBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?`

I think my bundles are correct:

```
    $bundles = array(

        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle(),
        new HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle()

    );
```

When trying to clear cache, getting this error, I think this is my problem:

[image]

My `services.yml` file:

`service:
    my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service:
        class: HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider
        arguments:
            userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
            properties: ["pass properties as array"]`

My default method in `Configuration.php`:

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('fos_user');
    $supportedDrivers = array('orm', 'mongodb', 'couchdb', 'custom');
    $rootNode
        ->children()
        ->scalarNode('db_driver')
        ->validate()
        ->ifNotInArray($supportedDrivers)
        ->thenInvalid('The driver %s is not supported. Please choose one of '.json_encode($supportedDrivers))
        ->end()
        ->cannotBeOverwritten()
        ->isRequired()
        ->cannotBeEmpty()
        ->end()
        ->scalarNode('user_class')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
        ->scalarNode('firewall_name')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
        ->scalarNode('model_manager_name')->defaultNull()->end()
        ->booleanNode('use_authentication_listener')->defaultTrue()->end()
        ->booleanNode('use_listener')->defaultTrue()->end()
        ->booleanNode('use_flash_notifications')->defaultTrue()->end()
        ->booleanNode('use_username_form_type')->defaultTrue()->end()
        ->arrayNode('from_email')
        ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
        ->children()
        ->scalarNode('address')->defaultValue('webmaster@example.com')->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
        ->scalarNode('sender_name')->defaultValue('webmaster')->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
        ->end()
        ->end()
        ->end()
        // Using the custom driver requires changing the manager services
        ->validate()
        ->ifTrue(function ($v) {
            return 'custom' === $v['db_driver'] && 'fos_user.user_manager.default' === $v['service']['user_manager'];
        })
        ->thenInvalid('You need to specify your own user manager service when using the "custom" driver.')
        ->end()
        ->validate()
        ->ifTrue(function ($v) {
            return 'custom' === $v['db_driver'] && !empty($v['group']) && 'fos_user.group_manager.default' === $v['group']['group_manager'];
        })
        ->thenInvalid('You need to specify your own group manager service when using the "custom" driver.')
        ->end();
    $this->addProfileSection($rootNode);
    $this->addChangePasswordSection($rootNode);
    $this->addRegistrationSection($rootNode);
    $this->addResettingSection($rootNode);
    $this->addServiceSection($rootNode);
    $this->addGroupSection($rootNode);
    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13743384/2568469

Comment: Or consider changing service to services.

Comment: After changing to `services`, getting this error `Fatal error: Class 'FOS\UserBundle\Util\LegacyFormHelper' not found in Configuration.php`

Comment: I'm very confused.  Did you install FOSUserBundle?  If so why did you post the TreeBuilder for it?

Comment: Maybe I something missmatched, but its generated automaticaly after install.What should I use in `configuration.php` instead?

Comment: Are you saying that FOSUserBundle was installed when you installed the OAuthBundle?  Okay.  But why are you fooling around with a Configuration class at all?  Just follow the instructions on the oath bundle.

Comment: I followed, but am getting that error in black picture and on website this:"`Attempted to load class "FOSUserBundle" from namespace "FOS\UserBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?` Maybe I need follow instructions and do it again

Comment: take a look at my https://github.com/Fbeen/UserBundle. Includes Facebook and Google logins

Comment: The unable to load FOSUserBundle strongly implies that you did not actually load stuff through composer.  It's a basic php namespace issue.  Yes, start over from scratch.  And if all your really need is a google login then maybe look for other bundles.  No idea if the one suggested by @FrankB is a good choice but I do know that both FOSUserBundle and the HWIAuthBundle are very much over-engineered and poorly maintained.  If you have any familiarity with oauth2 then just write the code yourself.