# Unable to install Sylius 1.3 in prod env, nelmio_alice error

Tags: sylius, sylius-1.3

Unable to install Sylius in prod env(Edited $APP_ENV = prod in .env file), getting this error when executing : sudo php bin/console sylius:install

But I am able to install in dev environment, please help!

[image]

---

```
Error.log
ubuntu@ip:/var/www/pwsstore_prod/Sylius$ sudo php bin/console sylius:install

In FileLoader.php line 168:

  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "nelmio_alice" (in  
   /var/www/pwsstore_prod/Sylius/config/packages/nelmio_alice.yaml). Looked f  
  or namespace "nelmio_alice", found "framework", "monolog", "security", "swi  
  ftmailer", "twig", "doctrine", "doctrine_cache", "sylius_order", "sylius_mo  
  ney", "sylius_currency", "sylius_locale", "sylius_product", "sylius_channel  
  ", "sylius_attribute", "sylius_taxation", "sylius_shipping", "sylius_paymen  
  t", "sylius_mailer", "sylius_promotion", "sylius_addressing", "sylius_inven  
  tory", "sylius_taxonomy", "sylius_user", "sylius_customer", "sylius_ui", "s  
  ylius_review", "sylius_core", "sylius_resource", "sylius_grid", "winzou_sta  
  te_machine", "sonata_core", "sonata_block", "sonata_intl", "bazinga_hateoas  
  ", "jms_serializer", "fos_rest", "knp_gaufrette", "knp_menu", "liip_imagine  
  ", "payum", "stof_doctrine_extensions", "white_october_pagerfanta", "doctri  
  ne_migrations", "doctrine_fixtures", "sylius_fixtures", "sylius_payum", "sy  
  lius_theme", "sylius_admin", "sylius_shop", "fos_oauth_server", "sylius_adm  
  in_api" in /var/www/pwsstore_prod/Sylius/config/packages/nelmio_alice.yaml   
  (which is loaded in resource "/var/www/pwsstore_prod/Sylius/config/packages  
  /nelmio_alice.yaml").                                                        


In YamlFileLoader.php line 657:

  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "nelmio_alice" (in  
   /var/www/pwsstore_prod/Sylius/config/packages/nelmio_alice.yaml). Looked f  
  or namespace "nelmio_alice", found "framework", "monolog", "security", "swi  
  ftmailer", "twig", "doctrine", "doctrine_cache", "sylius_order", "sylius_mo  
  ney", "sylius_currency", "sylius_locale", "sylius_product", "sylius_channel  
  ", "sylius_attribute", "sylius_taxation", "sylius_shipping", "sylius_paymen  
  t", "sylius_mailer", "sylius_promotion", "sylius_addressing", "sylius_inven  
  tory", "sylius_taxonomy", "sylius_user", "sylius_customer", "sylius_ui", "s  
  ylius_review", "sylius_core", "sylius_resource", "sylius_grid", "winzou_sta  
  te_machine", "sonata_core", "sonata_block", "sonata_intl", "bazinga_hateoas  
  ", "jms_serializer", "fos_rest", "knp_gaufrette", "knp_menu", "liip_imagine  
  ", "payum", "stof_doctrine_extensions", "white_october_pagerfanta", "doctri  
  ne_migrations", "doctrine_fixtures", "sylius_fixtures", "sylius_payum", "sy  
  lius_theme", "sylius_admin", "sylius_shop", "fos_oauth_server", "sylius_adm  
  in_api"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no extension able to load the configuration for "facebookbundle" symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741632/there-is-no-extension-able-to-load-the-configuration-for-facebookbundle-symfon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `nelmo_alice.yml` file from `config/packages/nelmo_alice.yml` into `config/packages/dev/nelmio_alice.yml`

(Create the `dev` folder in `packages` directory and add the `nelmio_alice` file)

Then, run the installation command as usual!